# How can I set the value of a variable inside a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView = (phs.phrases | orderBy:phs.phrasesOrderBy[phs.phrasesOrderById].key:phs.phrasesSortDirectionId == 1)"

    ***
    *** I want something here to set the value of pos ***
    *** based on array1.findIndex(v => v.phraseId == 'def') + 1; ***
    ***                        
 >
    <div>{{ phs.phrases[pos].phraseId }} </div>
    <div>{{ phs.phrases[pos].keyword }} </div>
```

I have this data:

```
var phs.phrases = [{
  "phraseId": "abc",
  "keyword": "bb",
  "posId": 1
}, {
  "phraseId": "def",
  "keyword": "bb",
  "posId": 1
}, ];
```

What I would like to do is to find the position of the row. I can't use $index as I want to find the position and have it displayed even after sorting.

I know I can use this code to find the pos, but how can I set it up so this code works for each row of the ng-repeat?

```
var pos = array1.findIndex(v => v.phraseId == 'def') + 1;
```

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "the position of the row" if you aren't referring to `$index`.  sorting the array changes the items positions;  if you somehow stored the index "before the sort" then displayed that value after the sort, it wouldn't be a useful value, since that item isn't necessarily in that array position anymore.  If having a fixed value for each object is necessary for some reason, that value would need to be a property of each object.

Comment: Store the position of each object inside the object itself: `phs.phrases.forEach(function(phrase, index) {phrase.position = index + 1;});` Or (much less efficient), call a function finding the position inside the ng-repeat: `{{ getPositionOf(row) }}`

Comment: @JBNizet - Can you propose your solution as an answer please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the position of each object inside the object itself:

```
phs.phrases.forEach(function(phrase, index) {
    phrase.position = index + 1;
});
```

Or (but his is much less efficient), call a function finding the position inside the ng-repeat:

```
{{ getPositionOf(row) }}
```